# How to get valid IETF language tag from a string

Tags: go, locale

I would like to convert locale tag to IETF standard.
IETF language tag asserts `en-US` as a correct tag for American English.
In may case, it's possible that I would get `en_US` as an input.

Currently I'm using this method:

```
func toLanguageTag(l string) string {
    return strings.Replace(l, "_", "-", -1)
}
```

For example, I know that Java has [`toLanguageTag`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#toLanguageTag()) method. Should I continue use this approach, or there is more preferable way to do what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a package in the external packages repository of Go (maintained by the Go project but not part of the standard library), that handles parsing and validation of language tags.

https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/language

Example:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "golang.org/x/text/language"
)

func main() {
   tag := language.Make("en_us")
   fmt.Println(tag)
}
// Output: en-US
```

Note that `language.Make()` omits the error in case of an invalid tag. You should use `language.Parse()` which returns an error in practice.

Comment: The dude abides